# Index out of bounds on setChildIndex?

Tags: actionscript-3, indexoutofboundsexception

OK so I have the following code...

```
function fire1(e:MouseEvent)
{
    firebb.addChild(fireb);
    fireb.x=firebb.x;
    fireb.y=firebb.y;
    fireb.parent.setChildIndex(fireb, numChildren-1);
    fireb.startDrag();
    pop.play();
}
```

what it's supposed to do, is create a child of the firebb Movieclip and change its depth (I use a custom cursor which is supposed to be on top of everything...but then I get this error when my game reaches this point.

```
RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/setChildIndex()
    at main_fla::MainTimeline/fire1()
```

setChildIndex worked flawlessly in previous frames, what's wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

```
fireb.parent.addChild(firWb);
```

or

```
fireb.parent.numberChildren -1
```

Comment: is this instead of `fireb.parent.setChildIndex(fireb, numChildren-1);`?

Comment: I actually made a new movieclip to hold both the fireb and the cursor...but yeah the .parent was the solution.